# Always retain the aggregation results from internal changelog topics created using KStream aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Apache Kafka kafka_2.13 version. As per our requirement, we are aggregating (arithmetic operations on some data fields) incoming stream data and storing final aggregation results for multiple windows (Hourly, Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Always Open Window) simultaneously. However, we don't want any window to get expire at all. e.g I should be able to see the aggregation result of the Hourly window which was created even a year back.

So basically, we don't want *-changelog (e.g topics like hourly-changelog, monthly-changelog) topics to purge the old aggregation data anytime. We are fine even if Kafka topic data increases.

What configuration or code practice am I supposed to follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `retention.ms=-1` if you never want Kafka to delete topic data.

But compact topics will never lose history, and always have the latest event for each unique key. For example, if you have window keys between two hourly timestamps like `2022-08-30:0900/2022-08-30:1000`, then no new record sends the same key, then it'll be stored forever.

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketeer.  1) The *-changelog topics get created implicitly with 1-day retention by default. How can I enforce the retention period of *-changelog topics to -1? Also, we can't have this property configured at the Kafka config file as we don't want all the topic's retention period as -1.  2) Yes, we have configured cleanup. policy=compact. However, in our case Key is always going to be the same across multiple window instances. Now Im bit confused with retention period vs cleanup policy and ideal way of configuring it wrt our usecase. Plz advise.

Comment: I believe you need to pre-create those topics with the configs you need. They follow a common naming pattern as long as you give the statestore a specific name, and maybe `client.id` in the Streams app config

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketer for the quick turnaround. In Kafka Stream, while materizlising aggrgeation result, I found one option where we need to define retention period. I will make use of this param to set value to -1. I will continue to set cleanup.policy=compact.